# Error while installing jasperserver

Tags: tomcat, java, linux

I am about to install a jasperserver instance on my server. This is not my first jasperserver installation and I did this already on my host system and on a lxc. But now for some reason I get following error when completing the installtion on another server:

```
Please wait while Setup installs JasperReports Server CP 5.6.0 on your computer.

 Installing
 0% ______________ 50% ______________ 100%
 #########################################

Warning: Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete 
correctly
 Error running /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.6.0/apache-ant/bin/ant import-ce 
-DimportFile=install_resources/export/js-catalog : 
BUILD FAILED
/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.6.0/buildomatic/bin/import-export.xml:260: The 
following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.6.0/buildomatic/bin/import-export.xml:158: Java 
returned: 255
```

Do you have an idea what could cause this error to happen ?

Answer (score -3):

Check your hostname using hostname, for example:

```
$ hostname
jasperserver
```

then update your /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost jasperserver
```

Then re run the installer.
It will be fine....:)

Comment: The proposed answer worked for me.. Edited the hosts file in /etc/hosts In my case my hostname was "computername.local" Thanks!